# converting dataset.Compute("Sum(TARGET_AREA)", "") to .toString("N")

Tags: vb.net, string, datagridview

I am trying to convert my computed database columns in my datagrid. I was able to compute the columns and wanted to fix the format of the results.

```
Label18.Text = dataset.Compute("Sum(TARGET_AREA)", "") & " (ha)"
```

An example of my output is 100000.00 (ha)
What I wanted for my output is to look like this 100,000.00 (ha)

I tried using .toString("N") but no luck.

my column type is Decimal and the others were Double.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.Format` method.

Example

```
value = 1234.567890
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Source: [MSDN Custom Numeric Format Strings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Here is an example using a DataTable - Note that you may want to check the sum if the column allows nulls. Also, the sum here is invoked over the datatable object not the dataset (as in your question) - This code has been automatically translated from C# - I assume it syntactically OK.

```
Dim dataset As New DataSet("ds1")
Dim dt As New DataTable("dt")

Dim dc As DataColumn = dt.Columns.Add("TARGET_AREA", GetType(System.Decimal))
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows.Add()
dr("TARGET_AREA") = 100000.0


Dim finalResult As String = ""
Dim value As Decimal
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim result_obj As Object = dt.Compute("Sum(TARGET_AREA)", "")

    If result_obj Is System.DBNull.Value Then
        value = 0
    Else
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(result_obj)
    End If

    finalResult = String.Format(value.ToString("0,0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) & " (ha)"

    Console.WriteLine(finalResult)
End If
Console.Read()
Return
```

Comment: the second code worked..i tried the code from the link but it's giving me an error about Cultureinfo..I tried the second code, it worked. However, I have about 5 of those sum that needs the same format..the code will take up some space to do it..Is there anyway that i can make it shorter?

Comment: For cultureInfo to work, you either reference it using System.Globalization.CultureInfo or you could use IMPORTS at the top of your code to import System.Globalization namespace. If you have to repeat the formatting, you could simply create a method in your class that accepts a decimal value as input and returns the formated string as output. Let me know if you have issue with that.

Comment: thanks..i was able to fix it..also since we're at it I am also having issue with my other totals that needs to be added.. Label20.Text = dataset.Compute("Sum (Project_Cost_Total)", "") that code is suppose to add the column where the numbers are separated with comma example, 1,000,222.00 + 1,000.00..it is giving me an error..any idea?.thanks

Comment: If the numbers are stored with commas, then the "Sum" method won't work because your DataColumn type is most likely to be of a string type. I suggest you check where you created the column and adjust the type to be a decimal type as in the example. The error you are getting is because numbers with "," sign are formatted and calculations work only on unformulated numerical types.

Comment: well, i needed it to be stored that way..but when i changed it to decimal it won't accept the comma

Comment: So the data in the table was stored as strings which is bad. The workaround is to loop through the table rows and not use the Sum method. Within the loop, parse the column value to get a number that you can compute with. If you have problems with this, start a new question.